# Load more content divs and stop the page at the "Load more" button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to apply an example for loading divs,

The problem is that during loading, the page does not stop at the Load more button to display the new displayed divs but it continues to the bottom of the page

I want stop the display at the last divs ?

Any idea please ?

```js
$(function () {
    $("div").slice(0, 8).addClass('display');
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div:hidden").slice(0, 8).addClass('display');
        if ($("div:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });
});

$('a[href=#top]').click(function () {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('.totop a').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.totop a').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font: normal 13px/100% sans-serif;
    color: #444;
}
div {
    height: 80px;
    display:none;
    padding: 10px;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
}
div.display {
    display: inline-block;
}
a, a:visited {
    color: #33739E;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#loadMore {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #33739E;
    color: #fff;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
    transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #33739E;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Content 1</div>
<div>Content 2</div>
<div>Content 3</div>
<div>Content 4</div>
<div>Content 5</div>
<div>Content 6</div>
<div>Content 7</div>
<div>Content 8</div>
<div>Content 9</div>
<div>Content 10</div>
<div>Content 11</div>
<div>Content 12</div>
<div>Content 13</div>
<div>Content 14</div>
<div>Content 15</div>
<div>Content 16</div>

<a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>

<ul>
<li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
<li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
<li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
<li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
<li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
<li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
</ul>
```

The result when you click on the button :

[image]

I need :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did u mean something like this

```js
$(function () {
    $("div").slice(0, 8).addClass('display');
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div:hidden").slice(0, 8).addClass('display');
        if ($("div:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - $(window).height() + 3 * ($(this).height())
        }, 1500);
    });
});

$('a[href=#top]').click(function () {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('.totop a').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.totop a').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font: normal 13px/100% sans-serif;
    color: #444;
}
div {
    height: 80px;
    display:none;
    padding: 10px;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
}
div.display {
    display: inline-block;
}
a, a:visited {
    color: #33739E;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#loadMore {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #33739E;
    color: #fff;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
    transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #33739E;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Content 1</div>
<div>Content 2</div>
<div>Content 3</div>
<div>Content 4</div>
<div>Content 5</div>
<div>Content 6</div>
<div>Content 7</div>
<div>Content 8</div>
<div>Content 9</div>
<div>Content 10</div>
<div>Content 11</div>
<div>Content 12</div>
<div>Content 13</div>
<div>Content 14</div>
<div>Content 15</div>
<div>Content 16</div>

<a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>

<ul>
<li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
<li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
<li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
<li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
<li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
<li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: small note. I only focus on ur requirement. there are better ways of achieving this behaviour. try these keywords "jq smooth scrolling","js smooth scrolling"

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the first hidden div in JS object (if there is any) and use its top property to scroll animation.

Please, Check below solution:

```js
$(function () {
    $("div").slice(0, 8).addClass('display');
    var scrollTopReq, tmpDivObj;
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        tmpDivObj = $("div:hidden").first();
        $("div:hidden").slice(0, 8).addClass('display');
        scrollTopReq = tmpDivObj.offset().top;
        if ($("div:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: scrollTopReq
        }, 1500);
    });
});

$('a[href=#top]').click(function () {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('.totop a').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.totop a').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font: normal 13px/100% sans-serif;
    color: #444;
}
div {
    height: 80px;
    display:none;
    padding: 10px;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
}
div.display {
    display: inline-block;
}
a, a:visited {
    color: #33739E;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#loadMore {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #33739E;
    color: #fff;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
    transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #33739E;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Content 1</div>
<div>Content 2</div>
<div>Content 3</div>
<div>Content 4</div>
<div>Content 5</div>
<div>Content 6</div>
<div>Content 7</div>
<div>Content 8</div>
<div>Content 9</div>
<div>Content 10</div>
<div>Content 11</div>
<div>Content 12</div>
<div>Content 13</div>
<div>Content 14</div>
<div>Content 15</div>
<div>Content 16</div>

<a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>

<ul>
<li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
<li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
<li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
<li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
<li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
<li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it's exactly what I'm looking for, it lacks a small detail, can we stop at the button itself and not the top of the div Please ? I want to display the button as well so that the client can click on it please ?

Comment: Thank you it is solved, look at the answer of ashen madusanka